# How can I get my element.style.background to use type="color" as value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get my divs to change color on mousedown using the value of my type="color". Currently, the divs change color successfully if I specify the value straight up like `element.style.background = 'black'` but I would like to give the user the option to choose the color via `type='color'`. Would someone be able to identify what is causing my `element.style.background` from using the value from `type='color'`?

html:

```
<div id="selectColor">
  Select a Color <input onchange="selectColor()" type='color'>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function colorPixel() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.contentDivs').forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
        element.style.background = selectColor();
        })
    })
    document.querySelectorAll('.horizontalDivs').forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
        element.style.background = selectColor();
        })
    })
}

function selectColor() {
    let colorSelected = document.getElementById('selectColor').value;
    element.style.background = colorSelected;
}
```

I can provide the rest of the code if that is helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to return the selected color in selectColor funciton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or return the color input value:

```
function selectColor() {
   return document.querySelector('#selectColor input').value;
}
```

```js
    document.querySelectorAll('.contentDivs').forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
        element.style.background = selectColor();
        })
    })
    document.querySelectorAll('.horizontalDivs').forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
        element.style.background = selectColor();
        })
    })


function selectColor() {
   return document.querySelector('#selectColor input').value;
}
```

```html
<div id="selectColor">
  Select a Color <input onchange="selectColor()" type='color'>
</div>


<div class='contentDivs'>
Div 1
</div>

<div class='horizontalDivs'>
Div 2
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! Did not think of returning the value but this is good info to know!

Answer (score 1):

The id should be assigned to the input not the div

```
<div>
  Select a Color <input onchange="selectColor()" id="selectColor" type='color'>
</div>
```